# Do border agents have a master key for BitLocker?

Tags: bitlocker

Do border agents have the master key to Bitlocker? A few years ago a Canadian border officer told me my computer with BitLocker could be deciphered by a Canadian security agency. Since this is Microsoft's flagship security product, his statement worries me.

Comment: lol, a underpaid border security sounds like a credible source for cryptographic insight.

Comment: "governments have a master key" is the case here. When you go through customs, they sometimes look at your notebook's files. The question is whether a government agency is able to decrypt your Bit Locker drive.

Comment: But Microsoft probably [has a copy of your decryption key](https://theintercept.com/2015/12/28/recently-bought-a-windows-computer-microsoft-probably-has-your-encryption-key/) right ? If they do (and they might), do you think they would cooperate with police perhaps ?

Comment: "governments have a master key"  and "border agents have the master key at hand" are, again, two different things.

Comment: And no, Bitlocker is not a "flagship security product". It's just a security product.

Comment: Maybe. Maybe not. If I had to bet: no. Are we able to answer your question? Probably no.

Comment: @Anonymous The article says "The gold standard in disk encryption is end-to-end encryption". Something about this sentence just sounds wrong

Comment: @TomK. I turned that into an answer. I'd like to make this canonical ...

Comment: @schroeder Love it

Comment: Has anyone ever reported their Bit Locker drive being accessed by Gov't agencies? I'd think these agencies would wish to avoid using such power, because people would find out that the product is insecure.

Comment: Rule #1: don't trust micro$oft or bill jails, Rule #2: don't trust micro$oft or bill jails...

Comment: sorry, what are "bill jails" ? The question remains, has anyone reported their computer being decrypted by security agencies?

Answer (score 4):

**No**. Such a "skeleton key" would undermine the entire security environment for BitLocker. If this was possible, this would be widely known and people would use alternate full disk encryption methods, rendering the "skeleton key" obsolete as soon as it was created.

**Maybe**. Governments might have some kind of a deal with Microsoft to unlock any BitLocker drive. But the existence of such a key would be a closely guarded secret and not disclosed to a border agent.

**Yes.** Government-level resources could eventually unlock a BitLocker drive, but such resources would take a lot of time and specialised work, and would not happen at the border in the minutes/hours a border agent might have your device.

So, in every case, you either are not correctly remembering what the border agent said or the border agent you talked to wanted to sound cool.

Comment: Microsoft has made it more and more difficult to **not** backup your bitlocker recovery key into their OneDrive for your protection. Even if you don't overtly make a OneDrive, they will automatically make one for you. It is still possible to avoid this behavior but you really have to work at it. That said, access to your OneDrive will access the recovery key if it's there. It's not a special Microsoft/Government deal, it's just Microsoft standard behavior.